# How to avoid dojo to parse an element

Tags: html, parsing, dojo, tags

---

I have a  elemetn in my page. I don't control all javascripts used in this page, and seems that in some place my "select" element is being parsed by dojo and changed to a dijit element (dijit.form.select).

This element does not have an attribute "data-dojo-type", so I don't know why it is being changed.

Is there someway to avoid dojo parse this element?

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><div dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox">Stuff</div></th>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Which version of Dojo?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the problem you have in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/zujCJ/11/). The `InlineEditBox` becomes a dijit, but the `<select>` does not. The example can try both Dojo 1.6.0 and Dojo 1.8.3:

HTML:

```
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: false
    };
</script>
<script>
    var v16 = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js";
    var v18 = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js";
    var dojoUrl = v18;
    document.writeln("<script src='" + dojoUrl + "'></scr" + "ipt>");
</script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            <div id="inlineEditBox1" dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox">Stuff</div>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select id="select1">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function dojo16ready() {
    if (!(dojoConfig && dojoConfig.parseOnLoad)) {
        dojo.parser.parse();
    }
}

function dojo18ready(parser, registry) {
    function go() {
        console.log("inlineEditBox1", registry.byId("inlineEditBox1"));
        console.log("select1", registry.byId("select1"));
    }
    if (!(dojoConfig && dojoConfig.parseOnLoad)) {
        parser.parse().then(go);
    }
}

function init() {
    console.log("dojo.version", dojo.version);
    if ("function" !== typeof require) {
        // Must require before onload
        dojo.require("dijit.InlineEditBox");
        dojo.addOnLoad(dojo16ready);
    } else {
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/InlineEditBox"], dojo18ready);
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: The issue is that the select is becoming a dijit, I don't know why and I need something to avoid it continue changing.

Comment: I understand that, my example exhibits no such issue. So I would start by comparing the two.